# How to block those annoying "Your device is infected" ads in Chrome without root

Tags: chrome-for-android, ads

We all know and hate them: those annoying ads that pop up along the lines of "Your phone is infected! Click to fix!" How can I block them in Chrome?

I know that adblock exists for root, but I do not have (or plan to) root.  And unfortunately a lot of sites host these adds, so it's not as easy as blocking or avoiding a specific site.

Phone: Alcatel Onetouch Idol S, Android 4.2.2 Jelly Bean.

**EDIT**
Device has root now.

Comment: No rooting significantly reduces available options. Be welcome to check my list of [Ad-Blocker](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_adblocker)s yourself (skip those with a "puzzle symbol" as they require root and Xposed).

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted? This looks like a legitimate question to me.

Comment: Now that device IS rooted, install Xposed and adaway module

Comment: @beeshyams Have. Try adding some fluff and putting it as answer, I prefer to give credit to others.

Comment: @DanB Many people do not like Xposed, and ad blocking can easily be achieved with root and without Xposed Framework. Adaway is one example that is included with many custom ROMs that eliminates a fair amount of ads and malware pop-ups. https://adaway.org/ The real answer is to stay away from sites that have these pop-ups, no legitimate site would have such ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you are rooted, you have a host of options and can be free from Google's policy of removing Ad blocking apps from play store

Install [Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) for your Android version and then [Adaway](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2190753) to block all ads. remember to keep updating hostfiles periodically

> AdAway is a utility for root users used to help manage hostfile entries. AdAway doesn't directly block ads; it limits unwanted ads by blocking servers that distribute those ads to websites

If you are not familiar with Xposed, [Xposed: The mighty Android tool box](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/xposed-intro) by Izzy, would be very useful